# android linear layout solution

Tags: java, android, layout

what i'm trying to achieve is #1 but what i get is #2

http://s48.radikal.ru/i120/1005/ff/6e439e04bbc8.jpg

it seems linear layout stacks with height of it's first element and shrinks second's element height to that.

the xml for those is the following:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:background="#FFFFEE"
>
 <ImageView 
  android:id="@+id/thumb"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/example" 
    android:layout_weight="5"
 />
 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/text" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" 
    android:text="Aaa aaaaa aaa aaaaa, aaaaaaa aaa aaa a, aaa aa aaaaaaa aaa aa. Aaa aaaaa aaa aaaaa, aaaaaaa aaa aaa a, aaa aa aaaaaaa aaa aa. Aaa aaaaa aaa aaaaa, aaaaaaa aaa aaa a, aaa aa aaaaaaa aaa aa. Aaa aaaaa aaa aaaaa, aaaaaaa aaa aaa a, aaa aa aaaaaaa aaa aa. Aaa aaaaa aaa aaaaa, aaaaaaa aaa aaa a, aaa aa aaaaaaa aaa aa. Aaa aaaaa aaa aaaaa, aaaaaaa aaa aaa a, aaa aa aaaaaaa aaa aa."
 />
</LinearLayout>`

Comment: could you pls post a correct version of your xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is incomplete and would help your question, but the obvious thing to try seems to be to include

`layout_height="fill_parent"`

in the attributes of the second element

Comment: hi. i've managed to achieve the needed by nest ImageView and TextView each in separate sub-layouts, but i'd love to have lighter solution if possible

Comment: I'm glad it's working. That XML looks fine now. It's a very light solution already, changing it would just complicate things. Is it performing badly?

Comment: unfortunately i can't nest image here so later it will become unavailable